# Angular 6 HttpClient Post not hitting API Post Method in DotNet Core 2.2 API Controller

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, controller, angular-httpclient

I have upgraded from MVC/AngularJS 1.x to DotNet Core 2.2/Angular 6.x. with @angular/common/http

Mostly it has been a breeze but the Web API is killing me. I got the get to work in a few minutes, but I have spent a week trying everything under the sun to get the Web Post to work.

What I have done here is really simple to replicate.

1. Go into Visual Studio 17 and clicked File/New Project
2. Choose Installed/Visual C#/.NET Core
3. Select the template: ASP.NET core Web Application
4. On the secondary screen set the dropdowns at the top to .NET Core and ASP.NET Core 2.2
5. Select the Red shield "A" Angular template
6. Let the project pull down the dependencies and rebuild.

EVERYTHING is the stock out of the box demo app from Microsoft except for:

1. Add the buttons to the screen.
2. Add code to the .ts to call the API Controller
3. Add the input parm to the get method in the controller
4. Add a very simple post method to the controller

I am also am trying to get 
DotNet Core 2.0/Angular 4.x. with @angular/http 
to work with the exact same results. The get was very easy, but I have tried every configuration under the sun to get the post to work. I will make a post like this for the other version as well. Right now, I am just trying to get whatever I can to work and leave AngularJS 1.x behind.

```js
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
  public Http: HttpClient;
  public BaseURL: string;
  public HttpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };
  public startDateIndex = 0;
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[] = [];
  public forecast: WeatherForecast = {
    dateFormatted: "3/27/2020",
    temperatureC: 0,
    temperatureF: 32,
    summary: "Cold Post"
  };

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.Http = http;
    this.BaseURL = baseUrl;

    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
      .subscribe(result => { this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
  }
  public OnClick(pControl: string) {
    //console.log("LogOn.OnClick * pControl=" + pControl);
    switch (pControl) {
      case "Prior":
        this.startDateIndex -= 5;
        this.Http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(this.BaseURL + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts/', { params: new HttpParams().set('startDateIndex', this.startDateIndex.toString()) })
          .subscribe(result => { this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
        break;
      case "Next":
        this.startDateIndex += 5;
        this.Http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(this.BaseURL + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts/', { params: new HttpParams().set('startDateIndex', this.startDateIndex.toString()) })
          .subscribe(result => { this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
        break;
      case "Post":
        console.log("Post * this.forecast=" + JSON.stringify(this.forecast) + "this.HttpOptions=" + JSON.stringify(this.HttpOptions));
        this.Http.post<WeatherForecast>(this.BaseURL + '/api/SampleData/PostWeatherForecast/', this.forecast, this.HttpOptions);
    }
  }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
  dateFormatted: string;
  temperatureC: number;
  temperatureF: number;
  summary: string;
}
```

```html
<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!forecasts"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table class='table table-striped' *ngIf="forecasts">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Temp. (C)</th>
      <th>Temp. (F)</th>
      <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let forecast of forecasts">
      <td>{{ forecast.dateFormatted }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureC }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureF }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.summary }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class='btn btn-default pull-left' (click)="OnClick('Prior')">Previous</button>
<button class='btn btn-default pull-left' (click)="OnClick('Next')">Next</button>
<button class='btn btn-default pull-right' (click)="OnClick('Post')">Post</button>
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace NG_22.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SampleDataController : Controller
    {
        private static string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts(int startDateIndex = 0)
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                DateFormatted = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index + startDateIndex).ToString("d"),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            });
        }
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public WeatherForecast PostWeatherForecast([FromBody] WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
        {
            var forecast = weatherForecast;
            //return weatherForecast;
            return new WeatherForecast()
            {
                DateFormatted = DateTime.Now.ToString("d"),
                TemperatureC = 30,
                Summary = Summaries[2]
            };
        }



        public class WeatherForecast
        {
            public string DateFormatted { get; set; }
            public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
            public string Summary { get; set; }

            public int TemperatureF
            {
                get
                {
                    return 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Stringify the data you're passing to the controller? You're using stringify in the log but not in the call

Comment: Haven't been around this sort of stuff for a while but I recall issues when your URL was generated as /WeatherForecast?startDateIndex="2" instead of /WeatherForecast/2 or vice versa. Will see if I can dig something up.

Comment: So I believe its your [Http*] attributes. Have a read of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2. Try changing [Route("api/[controller]")] to [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] and [HttpGet("[action]")] to just [HttpGet]. Im pretty sure it will be some combination of that.

Comment: ***  Have you tried Stringify the data you're passing to the controller? You're using stringify in the log but not in the call ***   I tried that, It did not work, even though I changed the header to text instead of JSON

Comment: ***   Haven't been around this sort of stuff for a while but I recall issues when your URL was generated as /WeatherForecast?startDateIndex="2" instead of /WeatherForecast/2 or vice versa.   ****     The Get, which uses the startindex, is working fine. The only problem is with the post

Comment: ****   So I believe its your [Http*] attributes. Have a read of learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/…. Try changing [Route("api/[controller]")] to [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] and [HttpGet("[action]")] to just [HttpGet]. Im pretty sure it will be some combination of that.   ***  Thanks! I will give that a try. At one point, in fiddling wth the code I had it hitting the Controller post method, but the parameters came through as null

Comment: *** Haven't been around this sort of stuff for a while but I recall issues when your URL was generated as /WeatherForecast?startDateIndex="2" instead of /WeatherForecast/2 or vice versa. ****  
 
I changed 
[Route("api/[controller]")] to [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]

and changed

[HttpGet("[action]")] to [HttpGet]

and changed 
 
[HttpPost("[action]")] to [HttpPost]  

The result was identical. The Get works fine but the post does not hit. It did streamline the code though.

Answer (score 5):

Solved it!!!!!

The problem was that there nothing subscribing. If no one is listening, it doesn't bother calling the Post. I added a .subscribe and it worked fine.

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
  public Http: HttpClient;
  public BaseURL: string;
  public HttpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };
  public startDateIndex = 0;
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[] = [];
  public forecast: WeatherForecast = {
    dateFormatted: "3/27/2020",
    temperatureC: 0,
    temperatureF: 32,
    summary: "Cold Post"
  };

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.Http = http;
    this.BaseURL = baseUrl;

    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
      .subscribe(result => { this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
  }
  public OnClick(pControl: string) {
    //console.log("LogOn.OnClick * pControl=" + pControl);
    switch (pControl) {
      case "Prior":
        this.startDateIndex -= 5;
        this.Http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(this.BaseURL + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts/', { params: new HttpParams().set('startDateIndex', this.startDateIndex.toString()) })
          .subscribe(result => { this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
        break;
      case "Next":
        this.startDateIndex += 5;
        this.Http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(this.BaseURL + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts/', { params: new HttpParams().set('startDateIndex', this.startDateIndex.toString()) })
          .subscribe(result => { this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
        break;
      case "Post":
        console.log("Post * this.forecast=" + JSON.stringify(this.forecast) + "this.HttpOptions=" + JSON.stringify(this.HttpOptions));
        this.Http.post<WeatherForecast>(this.BaseURL + '/api/SampleData/PostWeatherForecast/', this.forecast, this.HttpOptions)
          .subscribe(result => { console.log("Posted" + JSON.stringify(result)); }, error => console.error(error));          
    }
  }
}

interface WeatherForecast {
  dateFormatted: string;
  temperatureC: number;
  temperatureF: number;
  summary: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Improved answer. The Interface is not necessary and other smaller refinements and removal of unnecessary code.

```js
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders  } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
})
export class FetchDataComponent {
  public Http: HttpClient;
  public BaseURL: string;
  public HttpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };
  public startDateIndex = 0;
  public forecasts: any;
  public forecast = { dateFormatted: "3/27/2020", temperatureC: 0, temperatureF: 32, summary: "Cold Post", Data: { color: "red", Size: "Large" } };

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.Http = http;
    this.BaseURL = baseUrl;

    http.get(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
      .subscribe(result => { this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
  }
  public OnClick(pControl: string) {
    //console.log("LogOn.OnClick * pControl=" + pControl);
    switch (pControl) {
      case "Prior":
        this.startDateIndex -= 5;
        this.Http.get(this.BaseURL + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts/', { params: new HttpParams().set('startDateIndex', this.startDateIndex.toString()) })
          .subscribe(result => { this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
        break;
      case "Next":
        this.startDateIndex += 5;
        this.Http.get(this.BaseURL + 'api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts/', { params: new HttpParams().set('startDateIndex', this.startDateIndex.toString()) })
          .subscribe(result => { this.forecasts = result; }, error => console.error(error));
        break;
      case "Post":
        console.log("Post * this.forecast=" + JSON.stringify(this.forecast) + "this.HttpOptions=" + JSON.stringify(this.HttpOptions));
        this.Http.post(this.BaseURL + '/api/SampleData/PostWeatherForecast/', this.forecast, this.HttpOptions)
          .subscribe(result => { alert("Posted" + JSON.stringify(result)); }, error => console.error(error));          
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Weather forecast</h1>
<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>
<p *ngIf="!forecasts"><em>Loading...</em></p>
<table class='table table-striped' *ngIf="forecasts">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Temp. (C)</th>
      <th>Temp. (F)</th>
      <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let forecast of forecasts">
      <td>{{ forecast.dateFormatted }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureC }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureF }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.summary }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button class='btn btn-default pull-left' (click)="OnClick('Prior')">Previous</button>
<button class='btn btn-default pull-left' (click)="OnClick('Next')">Next</button>
<button class='btn btn-default pull-right' (click)="OnClick('Post')">Post</button>
```

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace NG_22.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] 
    public class SampleDataController : Controller
    {
        private static string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts(int startDateIndex = 0)
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                DateFormatted = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index + startDateIndex).ToString("d"),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            });
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public object PostWeatherForecast([FromBody] WeatherForecast weatherForecast)
        {
            var forecast = weatherForecast;
            //return weatherForecast;
            return new
            {
                DateFormatted = DateTime.Now.ToString("d"),
                TemperatureC = 30,
                Summary = Summaries[2]
            };
        }



        public class WeatherForecast
        {
            public string DateFormatted { get; set; }
            public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
            public string Summary { get; set; }
            public int TemperatureF
            {
                get
                {
                    return 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
                }
            }
            public object Data { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using DMChess_Data.Model;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DMChess_Data
{
    public class Entities
    {
        private dmchessContext DMCConnection = new dmchessContext();
        private Guid AppId = new Guid("B6C093C8-AE8C-40CD-9E0D-3BD2118422EC");
        public bool SaveChanges()
        {
            try
            {
                DMCConnection.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch(Exception pException)
            //catch (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.)
            //catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                var ex = pException;

                //foreach (var eve in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
                //{

                //    var type = eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
                //    var state = eve.Entry.State;
                //    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                //    {
                //        var propertyName = ve.PropertyName;
                //        var ErrorMessage = ve.ErrorMessage;
                //    }
                //}
                //var m = ex;
                throw;
            }
            DMCConnection.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }

        #region AUsers
        public AUsers AUsersGet(Guid pId, string pPassword)
        {
            return DMCConnection.AUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KAppId == AppId && x.KId == pId && x.Password == pPassword);
        }
        public AUsers AUsersGet(string pEmailAddress, string pPassword)
        {
            return DMCConnection.AUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KAppId == AppId && x.EmailAddress == pEmailAddress);
        }

        #endregion

        #region DProfiles

        public DProfiles DProfileGet(Guid pKUserId, int pKIdx)
        {
            return DMCConnection.DProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.KAppId == AppId && x.KUserId == pKUserId && x.KIdx == pKIdx);
        }

        public List<DProfiles> DProfilesGet(string pUserIdName)
        {
            return DMCConnection.DProfiles.Where(x => x.KAppId == AppId && x.UserIdToLower == pUserIdName.ToLower()).ToList();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    using D2Chess.Server.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;

namespace D2Chess.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class WebController : Controller
    {
        #region Init

        private JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        private Repository repository = new Repository();
        public WebController(IHubContext<D2Chess.Server.IO.Hub> hubContext) { D2Chess.Server.IO.Hub.StaticContext = hubContext; }

        #endregion

        #region Classes

        public class Parms {

            public Guid? TokenId { get; set; }
            public string Action { get; set; }
            public object Data { get; set; }
        }
        public class Result
        {
            public bool Success { get; set; }
            public object Data { get; set; }
            public Result(bool pSuccess, object pData = null) { this.Success = pSuccess; this.Data = pData; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Sync Methods

        [HttpGet]
        public object Get(string pAction, string pKey = "", Guid? pTokenId = null)
        {
            return repository.WebGet(pAction, pKey, pTokenId);
            //var result = repository.WebGet(pAction, pKey, pTokenId);
            //return result;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public object Post([FromBody] object pParms)
        {
            var parms = ((JObject)pParms).ToObject<Parms>();
            return repository.WebPost(parms.Action, parms.Data, parms.TokenId);
            //var result = repository.WebPost(parms.Action, parms.Data, parms.TokenId);
            //return result;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```